# what is the origin of CSS classes is ChormeDevTools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I wanted to know where ChormeDevTools takes its classes from?

I mean when you click in "elements" pane >"style">".cls">"add new class"
When you start typing something, CSS classes pop up at you, and I ask where they were taken from?

i want to know where to learn and inspect them

Attached a screenshot
[myscreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLcTD.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It's just css classes that are loaded with the page itself. Those classes are automatically detected by dev tools and are offered to you as options for auto-completion